# Given a list of lengths, and a string representing those lengths, do they match?

Tags: code-golf, string, puzzle-solver

Given a pattern representing a list of lengths, and a string representing those lengths, do they match?

<sub>For those interested, this is question equivalent to verifying if a row or column of a [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) may be correct. However, I have omitted all language relating to Nonograms to make the question less confusing for those unfamiliar with these puzzles.</sub>

### Input

Two lines of data, separated by a newline.

1. The first line will be a space separated list of integers, example:

   ```
   3 6 1 4 6
   ```

   This line **describes a pattern** of filled spaces of size equal to the integer list, separated by empty spaces of **unknown**, positive length that the second line must match. There may also be empty spaces at the beginning and end of the matched string.
2. The second line will be a line that that may or may not match the pattern in line one. It consists entirely of `#`, `x`, and `_`. This line is **guaranteed** to be **at least** as long as the *sum of the integers in the first line, plus the number of distinct integers, minus 1,* and can be longer. So the second line in this case is guaranteed to be at least `(3+6+1+4+6) + (5) - 1`, or 24 characters long. Here is an example 24 character line that matches the pattern in the first line:

   ```
   ###_######_#_####_######
   ```

#### Meaning of symbols:

- `#` This represents a filled box
- `x` This represents a box marked as "guaranteed to be empty"
- `_` This represents an unknown / unmarked box.

### Goal

The idea is to:

1. Validate that the second line could be a valid row that meets the pattern of the first line.

   - You must print an unambiguous error message (how you choose to do this is up to you; the examples below write `ERROR` but it doesn't need to be those 5 characters) if the unknown spaces cannot be filled out with either `#` or `x` to match the first line.
2. Print the **zero-indexed indices** of the integers that have been **completely placed** in the row, space delimited. *If there is ambiguity, **do not** print the index*.

### Examples:

```
Input:                    |  Output:    |  Reason:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 6 1 4 6                 | 0 1 2 3 4   |  This is a complete string that 
###x######x#x####x######  |             |  matches perfectly.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 1                     | 0 1 2       |  There is no ambiguity which filled cells 
#____xx___##__x_#         |             |  correspond to which parts of the pattern.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 1                     |             |  I don't know whether the filled block is
____#___x                 |             |  part of the 1, 2, or 1, so output nothing.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 1                     | ERROR       | The first unknown cell will create a block that
#_#x_#                    |             | matches either 1 1 or 3, but not 1 2.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 2 1                     | 0 2         | Even though we know where all the filled cells
#____#                    |             | must be, only 0 and 2 are actually filled here.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 1 1 1                   |             | There are so many possible ways to do fill this,
__#_______#____           |             | we don't know which indices are actually matched.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 4                       |             | Again, we don't know WHICH 4 is matched here, 
______x####________       |             | so output nothing.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 4                       | 0           | However, here, there's no room for a previous 4,
__x####________           |             | so the displayed 4 must be index 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
3                         | ERROR       | We can't fit a 3 into a space before or after
__x__                     |             | the x, so this is impossible to match.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 1 3                     | 0           | While we can match the 5, we don't know whether
x#####x____#____          |             | the single block matches the 1 or the 3.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 2 3                     | 1           | The two has been completely placed,
____##x##____             |             | even though we don't know which it is.
```

### Rules:

You may write a [program or function](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/17249), which receives the input as a newline delimited String or from STDIN (or closest alternative), and [returns the output as an space delimited String or printing it to STDOUT (or closest alternative).](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) You may optionally include a single trailing newline in the output.

Additionally, [standard loopholes which are no longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are **banned**.

Comment: This is for solving nonograms, right? It might help to mention nongrams since that makes the challenge make immediate sense for those who solve them.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Edited in response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Perl, 134 bytes

(includes 1 switch)

```
perl -pe '$p.="([#_]{$_})[x_]+"for@l=split;chop$p,$_=<>;/^[x_]*$p*$(?{$h[$_-1].=$$_ for 1..@l})(?!)/;$_=@h?join$",grep{$h[$_]!~/_/}0..$#l:ERROR'
```

Takes two lines of input from STDIN. Must be re-executed for every input.

The idea is to first extract all possible patterns that match the given lengths. For example, if we have the lengths `1 2` and the pattern `#_x_#_`, then the matching patterns are `(#, _#)` and `(#, #_)`. Then, concatenate the matched patterns for every index - for the example the result is the list `(##, _##_)`. Now, print the indices of all the strings in the list which have only '#' characters.

I got the method to extract all possible matches from a regex in Perl [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1066361).

- [Ungolfed and extended explanation](https://ideone.com/qmEH9G)
- [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ignuHo)

Comment: Cool. Could you add an ungolfed version and an ideone link please?

Comment: Sure, I have added the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: True example of how horrible a golfed code snippet can look! At least to me.

Comment: @Arjun Golfing tends to obfuscate code. There's beauty in golfed code, but only if you know the language it is written in.

Comment: I added a new example because one scenario was still ambiguous in the problem description. Fortunately, your program still works correctly in that case too.

Comment: @durron597 thank you for the bounty! I had a lot of fun working on this problem :)

Comment: Yeah, certainly there is! And you even get rep for clever solutions, adding to your achievements! (I am Arjun).